# Is there Mac version of DBAccess?

Tags: macos, dbaccess

I am using DBAccess in my iOS projects and I want to use it in OS X as well. However, even when in StackOverflow DBAccess title is "ORM for use on iOS and Mac OS X", I am not able to find OS X version.

Is it available now?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, its a couple of versions out but in the main it should be identical.

http://www.db-access.org/downloads

If you scroll down to v1.05.8 you will be in business.  I will post on here if we get an opportunity to build a later version.

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: DBAccess has now been replaced by the open source ORM Shark. It is API compatible, and is available on github. http://sharkorm.com and https://github.com/sharksync/sharkorm

So can be compiled on Mac OS directly.